# Making all layers in an SVG visible when exporting from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, svg

My QGIS project has multiple layers. I use a U.S. county map as my base, and higher-level layers have lines. When I use the simpleSVG plugin to export my view to an SVG, then open the file in a web browser, I only see the basemap. When I use the browser's web inspector to check the SVG file in detail, I see the SVG elements for the lines, but they appear invisible, not colored in.

What do I need to do to make QGIS export all layers with visibility?

Link to the SVG code I get when exporting only the lines: https://pastebin.com/36pnwRmZ. They appear invisible when I open the SVG file in browsers.

Comment: Does it have to be in SVG format?

Comment: @whyzar I think so. I want to make an interactive that will go on a web page.

Comment: If you select lines in layer panel and use simpleSVG do you export Lines ?

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa Actually, I just noticed the SVG elements do export, but are not colored in. I changed my question to reflect that. Instead of asking how to export, I should've asked how to export everything with visibility.

Comment: Can you publish svg xml code here please ?

Comment: How do you define your style ?

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa Added the SVG/XML code that QGIS exports when I select only lines. When you ask how I define my style, do you mean in QGIS? The lines are all "simple lines."

Comment: Add bgcolor=transparent to your graph attributes:
graph [bgcolor=transparent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your SVG export contain all path but 
We Can see

```
stroke="none" fill="none"
```

This could be caused by the new style library used by Qgis and not full suported by this plugin
Please try another style with the old library if it's compatible